# Angular2 and ui-router

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

In AngularJS we used pretty ui-router based on states. I expected to see the same in Angular 2, but did not.
Question is, is this a step backward or not?
If not, what are the benefits of a new Angular2 router?

Comment: `ui-router` for anguar2 is currently in alpha version, you can see [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.3/modules/ng2.html)

Comment: Thanks! It's very interesting! Is this a universal ui-router for Angular v.1 and v.2? [angular-ui/ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: State-based routing for Angular 2 version v1.0.0-beta.1 - progress)